# How can I improve performance of a query with the DATE() function?

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to compare the date field with time stamp filed, but the below date conversion taking long time and causing performance issue, could you please tell another alternate way in db2?

```
date_record <> date(date_rec_CREATE_GMTS)
```

where date_record - date type and date_rec_CREATE_GMTS TimeStamp. please help me?

Comment: What platform and version of DB2?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your platform and version supports it, try creating an "expression based" index.

```
create index myidx 
  on mytbl (date(date_rec_create_gmts) as create_date)
```